# How to determine which Azure Keyvault contains certain keys with Databricks dbutils

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, azure-keyvault

Is it possible to determine which keyvault holds certain keys with Databricks DBUtils.

For example, if I run dbutils.secrets.list("my_scope_dev") I will be able to see existing keys. Is there a way to use dbutils to locate which keyvault the key is in?

Answer (score 1):

**You can list secretScopes:**

```
dbutils.secrets.listScopes()
```

**You can list secret name:**

```
dbutils.secrets.list(scope="databricksscopename")
dbutils.secrets.list("databricksscopename")
```

***Note: You will need the key vault adminstartor role to perfrom the above***

If you want to  locate which keyvault the key is in?
There is no direct way using dbutils.
The below code you can use as a workaround.

```
import pandas
import json
import requests
#COMMAND ----------
#MAGIC %md ### define variables
#COMMAND ----------
pat           = 'XXXXXXX'  
workspaceURL  = 'XXXXXXXXX'
#COMMAND ----------
#MAGIC %md ### list secret scopes
#COMMAND ----------
response = requests.get(workspaceURL + '/api/2.0/secrets/scopes/list',\
            headers = {'Authorization' :      'Bearer '+ pat,\
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
pandas.json_normalize(json.loads(response.content), record_path = 'scopes')
```

- In the above code paste the workspace url in the format of
  'https://adb-1234567.89.azuredatabricks.net' Note, the URL must not end with '/'
- Paste PAT. Get it from settings > user settings.

[image]

**Reference:**

[How to manage azure-key-vault backed scopes in databricks.](https://www.tackytech.blog/how-to-manage-azure-key-vault-backed-scopes-in-databricks/)

Comment: Hi @DileeprajnarayanThumula, thanks for reaching out. I'm getting the error KeyError: 'scopes'. Any thoughts?

Comment: when are you getting the error ?while using the workarond?

Comment: I entered scopes = 'ourscope' ```pandas.json_normalize(json.loads(response.content), record_path = 'scopes')``` but got the error

Comment: Yes when using the workaround

Comment: Do you have the key vault adminstartor role?

Comment: in the workaround just use the pat token and workspaceURL

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256020/discussion-between-dileeprajnarayanthumula-and-patterson).